# What does 'for' do in Action Script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Just as title implies, my question is, what does the 'for' piece of code do in ActionScript 3? I apologize if this seems to be a stupid question; I've very recently started coding.

Comment: its a loop structure, it will loop over whatever code is in the code block until the conditions between the `( )` have been met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a type of loop.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

This says:

```
1. Create an int called i and set it to 0.
2. Check to see if i < 10.  If not, stop executing the for loop and move on.
3. Do something.
4. Add 1 to i.
5. Go back to #2.
```

Comment: Ah, alright, thanks for the answer. This really cleared things up.

Answer (score 1):

`for` is used to create a loop. It can be a loop trough an array:

```
var array:Array = [1,2,3];
for(var i:int = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

Or it could be an object.

```
var object:Object = {};
for(var i:String in object) {
    // do something
}
```

Or you could just have an loop like

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

A for loop through children on stage / Movieclip:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
    // do something
}
```

So you can do many things with the `for`.